# method of organizing a "Tag-based" system, where each tag is a different instance

Tags: tags, organization, connection

I am trying to create a tag-like system, only the tags have to be instances of other classes.

So lets say that I have this class and many other classes that each have a list of characteristics

```
Public Class President {
    Date inOffice;
    Date outOffice;
    Wars[] WarsDuringTerms;
    Politics politicalIdeology;
    // Other Characteristics

}
```

I need a way to have each "characteristic" to be a tag which will point to itself and any other instance that mentions that tag